# how to set up xen cloud with single machine

Tags: cloud, virtualization, xen

can we set up the xen cloud task with single machine? do we need a blank machine to set up xen cloud? i heard that we need to have the stripped down version of ubuntu(or any linux os) in order to install xen cloud...is it correct...i am new to xen environment. I put my project in one question.please refer the question..........  "providing the authentication of virtual machine of xenhypervisor/xencloud (please user id:979228 dtyler)"...........Any idea on xen and my project would be great to me......thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently two ways to set up the Xen Cloud Platform (XCP).

1) Install it with a ISO/CD install

http://xen.org/download/xcp/

2) Project Kronos

http://blog.xen.org/index.php/2011/07/22/project-kronos/